# Would the cosmological vacuum heat a hollow box?

Tags: vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

The energy scale of the cosmological vacuum is about $10^{-3}\mbox{eV}\approx10\mbox{K}$.

Imagine cooling an insulated hollow metal box with a vacuum inside it down to near $0\mbox{K}$ and then leaving it.

Would the vacuum energy inside the box heat it back up to $10\mbox{K}$?

Comment: Nope, vacuum is just vacuum. Dark energy does contribute to the expansion rate of the universe though, which in turn yields a temperature from the cosmological horizon. It's very low, $H \sim 10^{-33} \ \mathrm{eV} \sim 10^{-29} \ \mathrm{K}$.

Comment: Are you saying that although the vacuum has zero-point energy it can't actually transfer that energy to a material body?

Comment: Your false vacuum temperature is bad. Cosmic microwave background has $2.7~\text{K}$ temperature, so vacuum temperature must be by many orders of magnitude lower, let's denote it $T_v$. You can't cool down body temperature less than $T_v$, because it would mean that you need to isolate body from vacuum's virtual particles, which is of completely random nature (random vacuum fluctuations). They are uncontrollable. Even if they would, you would probably need to invest infinite amount of energy supply for doing that. So impossible in any way.

Answer (score 2):

$10K$ is not the temperature of the vacuum. It's the present-day temperature of the CMBR, to within an order of magnitude. If you put a cold box in a random location in the present-day universe, the CMBR will heat it to $2.7K$, from the outside in. It won't be heated from the inside because there's no CMBR there.

In a de Sitter spacetime, which is the future of our universe according to $ΛCDM$ cosmology, there is a nonzero temperature due to Hawking/Unruh radiation from the cosmological horizon, but it's ridiculously tiny: the energy scale is comparable to $hc/λ$ where $λ$ is the Hubble distance (on the order of 10 billion light years). Even that is the temperature of the Hawking/Unruh radiation, not the vacuum. The vacuum as such has no temperature. (Its temperature is not even $0$, but undefined.)